# Deserialize Json into Map<UserInfo,Set<Long>>

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I wish to deserialise the following jsonArray directly into a Map object

```
[ { “userId": 1234, "userName": “abc”, "someList": [ 234, 12, 126, 137 ] }, 
{ "userId": 423, "userName": “mac”, "someList": [ 234, 2235, 226, 227 ] } ]
```

into `Map<UserInfo, Set<Long>>`

userId and userName are to be put into UserInfo class and someList into `Set<Long>`.

userinfo class is as follows

```
public class UserInfo {
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    private String preference;

    public UserInfo(@JsonProperty("userId")int userId, @JsonProperty("userName")String userName) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public UserInfo() {
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }


    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPreference() {
        return preference;
    }

    public void setPreference(String preference) {
        this.preference = preference;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserInfo [userId=" + userId + ", userName=" + userName
                + ", preference=" + preference + "]";
    }


}
```